# Загрузка файла с интернета

Tags: c++, winapi, curl, download

Хочу сделать загрузку файла по ссылке (пример - http://example.com/test.dll), но получаю в ответ HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Я понимаю в чем проблема, мне нужно задать юзер агент, но как это сделать?
Использую URLDownloadToFile(), пытался использовать curl, но подключить его не вышло.

Язык - C++